# Nothing happens when click links on drupal Home Page

Tags: php, apache, drupal-7

I newly installed drupal 7.14 and installation goes fine. But after installation on the Drupal Home Page when I click any link It goes to "Index of" page and shows the site content list. For example, when I click dashboard on the home page, the URL shows: `https://localhost/testdrupal/?q=admin%2Fdashboard&` But it shows me the "Index of" page with site content. Why this happening? How can I fix this? Please help me. Thanks...!

My web server is Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer. This happens because of the default Apache configuration does not allow overriding .htacces files. So you have to edit AllowOveride in httpd.conf.